# How to use variables in strings?

Tags: javascript, variables

This is probably a very simple thing to do but I am having trouble using variables in my strings although following usual protocol.

Here is my code:

```
 else if (weatherDesc.includes(desc)) {
        message.innerHTML = 'Look out for ${desc}';
    }
```

not really sure why this is not working, I tried switching from single quotes to double.

Comment: Use backwards quotes ``` not `'`

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) by wrapping text in **backtick** and not single quote like you did

```
message.innerHTML = `Look out for ${desc}`;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use backtick character:

```
message.innerHTML = `Look out for ${desc}`;
```